# Save WhatsApp audio file to music folder

Tags: whatsapp, music

I found my audio file received on WhatsApp, now how can I save this into my music folder?

Comment: http://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/9493/copy-of-audio-file-from-whatsapp
Check this for answer

Answer (score 3):

The audio will get stored only in the app's internal storage. You cannot move that to any other folders/ or phone's memory.

Answer (score 2):

There is a simple method to do so. The audio received by WhatsApp is stored in the following folder:
Files → SD card → Pictures → WhatsApp

You can just open this and copy that audio file to the music folder on your SD card, and your audio file will automatically appear in your music list.

Comment: Nope..You will not find any audio file via whatsapp in [FILES>>SD CARD>>PICTURES>>WHATSAPP]. It's not possible to get the audio file from whatsapp.

Comment: It is actually. Check the folder specified. All audio and other files received via WhatsApp are found there