# copy of audio file from WhatsApp

Tags: whatsapp

how can i copy the audio file received from WhatsApp in lumia 520. there is only forward &delete options are showing can any body help me

Comment: Where would you like to copy it to? Do you want to send it to another person or download the Audio file to your pc?

Answer (score 1):

The latest update of WhatsApp supports audio file.
So if you recieve any audio file from any person and you download it,then it will be saved in SD Card->Pictures->WhatsApp.
There you will see all the files from WhatsApp including audio files.

Answer (score 0):

The audio files doesn't get stored on SD Card or Phone's storage.. In fact, they get stored under app's internal storage, that can't be accessed through any file explorer..

Comment: but it does not work on windows 10 or 8.1 mobiles like Microsoft Lumia 535. i could not find the audio in my my phone anywhere nor in sd card.yeah videos from whatsapp show up in picture folder.